# How do I pass an array in ARGV command line arguments?

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

=== My program test.rb

```
def test (app, download, launch )
  for i in 0..(app.length - 1)do
    #DO SOMETHING HERE WITH THIS
    p  app[i].to_s + download[i].to_s + launch[i].to_s
  end
end
test (ARGV[0].split(//) , ARGV[2].split(//) ,ARGV[1].split(//))
```

=== other program "other.rb" that parses and executes test.rb

```
app = ["fda","asdf"]
down =  ["ok","nok"]
la = ["ok","ok"]
system("ruby test.rb #{app} #{down} #{la}")
```

I would like to print it as something like this:

```
fda ok ok
asdf no nok
```

However it is printed like this:

```
foo 
dkk 
ano
aok
sk
d
f
```

How can I pass arrays to the app correctly?

Comment: Is this homework? The parameters and what you're trying to do seems more academic than practical.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your source and pasted it into two files:

test.rb:

```
def test (app, download, launch )
  for i in 0..(app.length - 1)do
    #DO SOMETHING HERE WITH THIS
    p  app[i].to_s + download[i].to_s + launch[i].to_s
  end
end
test (ARGV[0].split(//) , ARGV[2].split(//) ,ARGV[1].split(//))
```

and test2.rb:

```
app = ["fda","asdf"]
down =  ["ok","nok"]
la = ["ok","ok"]
system("ruby test.rb #{app} #{down} #{la}")
```

Using Ruby 1.9.2p290, I get this result when I run your code:

```
ruby test2.rb
test.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
test (ARGV[0].split(//) , ARGV[2].split(//) ,ARGV[1].split(//))
                        ^
test.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end
test (ARGV[0].split(//) , ARGV[2].split(//) ,ARGV[1].split(//))
```

That tells me you didn't accurately report the problem you're seeing.

Fixing the syntax error returns this:

```
ruby test2.rb
"[[a"
"fos"
"dkd"
"a,f"
",]"
```

The output I got is what I would expect from your code, however it doesn't resemble what you said you got, so I doubt your reported output is correct. Please be accurate when you ask for help, both in the code you've written and the output you've seen.

Looking at the data your code is passing shows the arguments are:

```
0 [fda,
1 asdf]
2 [ok,
3 nok]
4 [ok,
5 ok]
```

FYI, I got those using this bit of code in place of `test.rb`:

```
ARGV.each_with_index do |a, i|
  puts "#{i} #{a}"
end
```

I'd expect that, because `system("ruby test.rb #{app} #{down} #{la}")` doesn't do what you think it does. Here is what the actual command sent to the sub-shell looks like when `system` processes it:

```
test.rb [fda, asdf] [ok, nok] [ok, ok]
```

Again, that matches what the arguments look like when the app sees them.

To understand what is happening, you need to read the documentation for `system`:

```
system([env,] command... [,options])    -> true, false or nil

[...]

command... is one of following forms.

[...]

  cmdname, arg1, ...          : command name and one or more arguments (no shell)
```

So, `system` allows us to send all the parameters separately, which is really what you want. Changing `test2.rb` to:

```
app  = %w[ fda asdf ]
down = %w[ ok  nok  ]
la   = %w[ ok  ok   ]

system(
  "echo",
  "test.rb",
  %Q["#{ app.join(',')  }"],
  %Q["#{ down.join(',') }"],
  %Q["#{ la.join(',')   }"]
)
```

gives me this on the command-line:

```
ruby test2.rb
test.rb "fda,asdf" "ok,nok" "ok,ok"
```

Which seems a bit more usable. Because of how `system` works, I can clean it up and reduce that a bit to:

```
app  = %w[ fda asdf ]
down = %w[ ok  nok  ]
la   = %w[ ok  ok   ]

system(
  "ruby",       # execute this
  "test.rb",    # with this script name
  app.join(','), down.join(','), la.join(',') # and these parameters
)
```

Looking at what `test.rb` sees shows:

```
ruby test2.rb
0 fda,asdf
1 ok,nok
2 ok,ok
```

Again, an improvement and closer to what your code expected.

I am not going to finish correcting your code because I suspect this is a homework assignment and not a practical use. Some hints  to help you are:

- Your use of `split` isn't correct, nor is it where I would put it.
- Your use of `for` is not idiomatic Ruby. Look at `Array.each` *AND* learn why it is preferred instead of `for`.
- Your use of `to_s` is unnecessary, since you are already dealing with strings and characters.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [Thor](https://github.com/wycats/thor) which is a dsl for creating command line apps